# Cannot get data and add it to a google sheet

Tags: python, json, rest

I am doing a 100 days of code python challenge and this one got me.

I am using sheety and tequila. The code is supposed to look at the "City" column in in my Google sheet, grab the IATA Code for each city then update the sheet with the codes. Print() reveals the program is reading the information in the sheet, but the IATA Code column remains blank. The data in the sheet is being read, but I can't fetch the iata codes and put them into sheet.

I tried:
looking at the Sheety documentation, and changing the key, value pairs to what is required.
making sure Sheety is set to enable get, put, and post.
checking my indentation
checking typos
checking if I changed the names of variables, etc. since I did this over a few days.
inserting a print command to see what the json is doing.

```
import os
import requests

#CONSTANT
SHEETY_API = os.getenv("SHEETY_API")
SHEETY_ENDPOINT = "https://api.sheety.co/d741b494d378a4eff912af14a92fd22e/metroSkies/prices/2"
class DataManager:
  # Initialization
  def __init__(self):
      self.destination_data = {}

  def get_destination_data(self):
      headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {SHEETY_API}"}
      response = requests.get(url=SHEETY_ENDPOINT, headers=headers)
      response.raise_for_status()
      data = response.json()
      print(response.json)
      self.destination_data = data["prices"]
      return self.destination_data

  def update_destination_codes(self, updated_data):
      for destination in updated_data:
          new_data = {
              "price": {
                  "iataCode": destination["city"]
              }
          }
          response = requests.put(
              url=f"{SHEETY_ENDPOINT}/prices/{destination['id']}",
              json=new_data,
              headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {SHEETY_API}"}
          )
          print(response.text)  # For debugging
```